# Do not assign concrete values to symbols

Tags: z3

I use Z3 to solve some constraint.

I invented an expression "x^m@mx where x noteq T". Someone provides "S^a".

We know "x^m@mx where x noteq T" can start with "S^a", on the condition that "x=S,a=m, x noteq T ".

Since this condition is satisfiable, "x^m@mx where x noteq T" will evaluate to "S^a@aS" by applying the condition.

So, I want to use Z3 to check if the conditions are satisfiable.

```cs
var ctx = new Context();

EnumSort domain = ctx.MkEnumSort("domain", new string[] { "S", "T"});

var x = ctx.MkConst("x", domain);
var m = ctx.MkConst("m", domain);
var a = ctx.MkConst("a", domain);

var solver = ctx.MkSolver();
solver.Add(ctx.MkEq(x, domain.Const(0))); // x=S
solver.Add(ctx.MkEq(a, m)); // a=m
solver.Add(ctx.MkNot(ctx.MkEq(x, domain.Const(1)))); // x noteq T

if (solver.Check() == Status.SATISFIABLE)
{
    Console.WriteLine(solver.Model);
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("Not satisfiable");
```

The model is m=S, a=S, x=S. This is wrong because my expression will step to "S^S@SS"

I want to leave `a` unassigned because later users can provide concrete values for `a`.

So how do I stop Z3 from assigning values to `a`?

It's OK to show me Python code.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather confusing: What constraints are you trying to satisfy exactly? But, in general, SMT solvers do not calculate symbolic models. That is, when they determine `sat`, then there's an assignment to all the variables. (Note that if a particular choice isn't forced on a variable, then they'll take one of the possible values.)

So, if you don't want `a` to receive value, do not make it a parameter of your system:

```py
from z3 import *

domain, (S, T) = EnumSort('domain', ('S', 'T'))

x = Const('x', domain)
m = Const('m', domain)

s = Solver()
s.add(x == S)
s.add(x != T)

if s.check() == sat:
    print(s.model())
else:
    print("Unsat")
```

Of course, the above is rather pointless: If you have `s.add(x == S)`, then `s.add(x != T)` is irrelevant since `x == S` automatically implies `x != T` for an enumerated type.